# View not painted in a particular case

Tags: android, draw

Dear Stack Overflow Users,

I am exploiting the Vintage Thermometer Template of this example (source code downloadable)
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

The only part of code I modified is the parametrization of the background image and the scale. My trial app works fine, both in the emulators (A phone 4.0' Android 4.3) and a Tablet (7.0' Android 4.4.2), and my phones, a Galaxy S Plus, and a Galaxy S III.

Since the code seemed to work I moved the view to another project where I'm using the Thermometer as Speedometer. Here again, everything is fine, both in the emulators and my Galaxy S Plus..., but not in the Galaxy S III!

What does work and what doesn't: everything works but the method *drawHand()* apparently. The hand is not painted for some reason. And just in this new project just with the Galaxy S III.

Now, everything in the layout and the code seems OK. I can't find cross compatibility issues anywhere. What I am asking you is maybe a more general question: something like this can actually happen and why? I searched for days for some similar issue without finding anything.

The view is inflated in the same way:

```
<com.example.speedometer.Tachimetro
    android:id="@+id/tachimetro2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.5" />
```

inside a linear layout.

The manifest has nothing except the call for the main activity.
Galaxy S III is the only phone where something is not painted.

[image: This is what I see, except in a Galaxy SIII where needle is not painted]

That's weird. Any idea what could be my next step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for late response, but please try disabling hardware acceleration. One way to do that is to add the following to your manifest file:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```

Comment: @wtomas, your answer is late but effective. It solved! And I still didn't have any clue about this, neither I knew about hardware acceleration gives problem on Android as  [it gives on Chrome](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?265194-black-screen-issue-on-Google-Chrome-since-v27). HA seems hostile to Google. Really, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Related solution to wthomas, instead of manually disabling hardware acceleration, in the mayou can target API 13 or less:

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="3"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

- it was after API 14 (4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich) that hardware acceleration became "automatic."